# Which security features are disabled when I start wireshark?

Tags: 10.10, security, network-monitoring

I want to know which security features are disabled(if any)  when i start **wireshark** in Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark does not start any services or open any ports, although it may perform network activity if you have it configured to resolve IP addresses to DNS names.

If you wish to avoid running Wireshark as root, you can use the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

This gives additional privileges to the `dumpcap` tool, which is the back-end of Wireshark which actually performs the packet sniffing, so that the entire Wireshark application does not need to run with root privileges.

More information about Wireshark privileges on Linux is available [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges).

Comment: Hi, i think i asked the question in an incorrect manner. I have not reformatted my question. See,if you can help out.

Comment: The answer is more or less the same — Wireshark doesn't specifically or intentionally introduce any security holes or disable any features, but the general advice not to run as root still holds in case there is a bug or exploit in the Wireshark application.

Answer (score 0):

When I start wireshark i got a "device eth0 entered promiscuous mode".
(running wireshark non-root)
Wireshark has a weakness: lots of code. A gentoo dev described it as a security issue. running wireshark non-root: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1420930
Alternative: run a apparmored tcpdump,it comes with an apparmor profile. Run it: tcpdump -n -i eth0 > tcpdump.txt gzip tcpdump.txt.